# referencing additional product ID within main ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am newish to php and developing an online shop. On my `item.php` I would like to reference 2 additional upsell id's on the same page that go well with the main `product_id`.

This is how my current page looks. [image]

I have added 2 new columns to my products table namely `product_upsell_one` and `product_upsell_two` which in essence hold the id's of existing products.

My products table:

[image: products table]

My images table:
[image]

and I call out each upsell image with this function

```
function get_upsell_image_for_product_upsell_one() {



$query = query("SELECT product_image, product_title, product_price FROM products WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_upsell_one FROM products WHERE product_id =   " . escape_string($_GET['id']) . " )");      
confirm($query); //runs the confirm method above 


while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {

$product_image = display_image($row['product_image']); // runs display image function    


$upsell = <<<DELIMETER




            <ul class="product-list">

                <li>

                    <div class="product">

                        <a href="#" class="product-image">


                            <img src="../resources/{$product_image}" alt="Product">

                        </a>




                        <div id="container">

                            <div id="box">

                                <a href="#" class="btn-view">{$row['product_title']}</a>

                            </div>


                        </div>


                    </div>

                </li>

            </ul>








DELIMETER;

echo $upsell;


} //closes while loop



} // end of function
```

Though my code works fine in dev mode, I am wondering if I am setting myself up for problems in production environment and would be best served by referencing `product_upsell_one` and `product_upsell_two` in a separate table. How best are additional IDs referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a product upsell table with a foreign keys pointing to the parent product and the upsell items. That way you can have as many or as few upsell items as you want.

Comment: appreciate the steering, may I ask is there much wrong in the way I have constructed this as it stands

Comment: not really wrong but, it will be a bit harder to change in the future. If you think they'll only ever have two than your way is probably fine.